# Impact of Obtenebration on the (Pen)Umbra

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, werewolf-the-apocalypse, umbra

Let's assume a Garou and a Lasombra meet each other in battle. The Lasombra uses an Obtenebration power like Arms of the Abyss and the Garou steps sideways into the Umbra. What would he see?

My take is that since the Obtenebration powers are tied to the Abyss (it's where Lasombra got this power IIRC) and the Abyss is a umbral realm it would reflect rather badly on the penumbra surrounding the battle field. But I couldn't quite put it into game mechanics. Would there be banes or something else entirely?

So what would happen if a Garou escapes Obtenebration of a Lasombra by stepping sideways?

Answer (score 4):

## Fair Escape

Lasombra have a power that may indeed come from the abyss, but it has no effect on any other plane, if for no other reason than Masquerade does not concern itself with other planes (and other planes are generally hostile to vampires).  The werewolf has simply fair-escaped the Lasombra attack.

## What would the puppy see?

They would see whatever of the skinlands they can see when they step sideways.  Nothing more, nothing less.

***In summary, nothing special happens in the situation you described.***

Comment: Do not argue in comments. Provide a better answer if you object to this one.

Answer (score -1):

The source of the [obtenebration](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Obtenebration_(VTM)) are unknown:

> The exact nature of this Discipline is unknown even among its greatest masters, and it has been a subject of religious, philosophical, and metaphysical debate among vampires for millennia

— so it's hard to say that it is indeed taking power from the Abyss. However it is perceived as VERY EVIL, which indeed might prove its infernal source or if you use Mage's concept of consensual reality - everything is true if enough people believe its true - might actually give it such sources. Or probably both - question about chicken and egg.

Anyway: such evil act will attract attention of banes, in a similar fashion as would i.e. cruel murder. So my answer is that the Garou would escape unharmed by the discipline itself but it might get himself surrounded by curious banes attracted to such act.